# How can the numbers in array count to odd or even number?

Tags: java

I wrote the code in java but it does not count to odd or even. It only counts in even numbers. If I miss anything?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddEven {
    //create the check() method here
    static void check(int[] x, int n) {
        x = new int[100];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            x[n++] = in.nextInt();
        }

        if (x[n] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("You input " + n + " Even value");
        } else if (x[n] % 2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("You input " + n + " Odd value");
        }
        while (in.hasNextInt()) ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //read the data here
        System.out.print("Input a list of Integer number : ");

        int[] x = new int[100];
        int n = 0;
        check(x, n);

        in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please clearly state ([edit] your post) what your code is supposed to do, what result you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: ProTip: Don't initialize your scanner more than once, and don't override the values being passed in (you accept an `int[] x` and then immediately override that with `x = new int[100]`), and don't call `in.nextInt()` more than once per loop.

Comment: Not only that, but try to get into the habit of naming your variables properly. It's hard to know what's supposed to be happening with variables like `x` and `n`. Anybody can write code but not every can write code that others can read.

Comment: Please check your logic. What do you think this line does? `while(in.hasNextInt());` Does your `if` condition is executed multiple times? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

Check these loops:

This essentially puts all the ints in x.

```
 while(in.hasNextInt()) {
        x[n++] = in.nextInt();  
    }
```

This just loops until it doesn't have an it.

```
while(in.hasNextInt());
```

Which means, the if block is not even in a loop.  However, the first while loop post increments n, which means even if you have one number, it will assign:

```
x[0] = 123;
```

but then n=1.  which means, the if block will check the next field.  But by default it is 0, which will display that it is even.

This would make more sense:

```
x= new int[100];
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(in.hasNextInt()) {
        x[n] = in.nextInt();  

         if(x[n]%2==0){

             System.out.println("You input "+n+" Even value");

         }else if(x[n]%2==1){

             System.out.println("You input "+n+" Odd value");

         }
         n++;
   }
```